# IndexError: list index out of range (Object Detection)

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

```py
import cv2
thres = 0.45 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)   
cap.set(3,1280)
cap.set(4,720)
cap.set(10,70)

classNames= []
classFile = 'coco.names'

with open(classFile,'rt') as f:
    classNames = f.read().rstrip('n').split('n')

configPath = 'ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt'
weightsPath = 'frozen_inference_graph.pb'

net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath,configPath)

net.setInputSize(320,320)
net.setInputScale(1.0/ 127.5)
net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
net.setInputSwapRB(True)

while True:
    success,img = cap.read()
    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img,confThreshold=thres)
    print(classIds,bbox)

    if len(classIds) != 0:
        for classId, confidence,box in zip(classIds.flatten(),confs.flatten(),bbox):
            cv2.rectangle(img,box,color=(0,255,0),thickness=2)
            cv2.putText(img,classNames[classId-1].upper(),(box[0]+10,box[1]+30),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),2)
            cv2.putText(img,str(round(confidence*100,2)),(box[0]+200,box[1]+30),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),2)

    cv2.imshow("Output",img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

The error message:

```
line 31, in <module>
    cv2.putText(img,classNames[classId-1].upper(),(box[0]+10,box[1]+30),
IndexError: list index out of range
[ WARN:1] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wvn_it83\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (434) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

Why is this list index out of range and what can I do to fix it?

'coco.names' , 'ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt' and 'frozen_inference_graph.pb' are including in the following link:
https://mega.nz/file/UIlQ1L7Y#ePLIQMSlhwo6ab46f1GgYli9nNw6EFIE6mb33-GZnHs

Comment: to reproduce it, we would need : `coco.names` , `ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt` and `frozen_inference_graph.pb`. pls provide their source or these files. Thanks

Comment: Yeah you were right, i just did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `classNames` were not getting build properly that is why you were getting **index out of range**.

for example, you got class id as 47(which is a cup) but an entry for 46(classid -1) was not present in classNames.

so the fix would be:

```
with open(classFile,'rt') as f:
    classNames=[line.rstrip() for line in f]
```

below is a demonstration before and after the above fix:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, now its better and it's running but this error is appearing:  line 25, in <module>
    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img,confThreshold=thres)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wvn_it83\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4051: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'  . Do you have any idea why it 's showing this error?

Comment: seems like the image is not matching with cv2. before `net.detect`, can you display the image so you know if the webcam is sending an image to your program? I was able to run this successfully, so something with webcam image.

Comment: yeah, it actually runs good with the webcam but it shows this error when i test it with videos (.MOV and .AVI files if it matters)

Comment: I had a sample mp4 file and it worked, although the accuracy was not that good it did not give any error. If you have any public domain video I can try to reproduce the error.

Comment: in a while loop, you need to break the loop once `success,img = cap.read()` success fails. something like this `if not success: break`